# External Hard Drive Name LXDE vs LXQt

Tags: desktop-environments, lxde, lxqt

I have a quick question about an external hard drive. When installed on the same exact system, with the LXDE desktop environment, it displays as "Backup Drive". When I switch the desktop environment to LXQt, it then displays as "TOSHIBA XXX: Backup Drive".

Is there a way to switch the LXQt desktop environment to just display the short drive name like LXDE does?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify OS/release details for each, plus where you are seeing this detail. Is it the file manager (`pcmanfm` for lxde, `pcmanfm-qt` for lxqt, or something else?).

Comment: From my experience, it does with with any current release of LXDE, and the LXQt release 0.14.1 used by Lubuntu 20.04. On LXDE it will show "Backup Drive" on both `pcmanfm` and the desktop. On LXQt, it shows "TOSHIBA XXX: Backup Drive" on both `pcmanfm-qt` and the desktop. Is this a setting that can be tweaked to just show the short name?